# Preventing Xpath Injection on .net 2.0

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, .net-2.0

I have the following code to get some translations for an old site (its also like this in some other functionality that have more important information.)

```
Dim myDoc As New XmlDocument
myDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("\GlobalContent\TranslationXML\TranslationXML.xml"))
Dim translationText As XmlNodeList = myDoc.SelectNodes("Transaltions/language[@code='" + hLang.Value + "']")
```

The Hlang comes from user input,As you can see this is vulnerable to Xpath injection Attacks.

I'm trying to apply the same thing i do with SQL injection that is the use of parameters, but haven't found how to do it in 2.0

I have tried this tutorial : http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/10/07/30888.aspx

But the *DynamicContext* is just part of a library and i cant use it.

**Can anyone guide me about how can i fix this?**

Comment: You could use a Regex to validate hLand.Value and discard what looks like XPATH; see 'XPath injection prevention' chapter here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xpathinjection/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither XmlDocument nor XPathDocument offer a good means of compiling XPaths with substitution (similar to a compiled SQL query). So, I recommend a slightly more verbose but secure approach - Use the primary XPath to get a XmlNodeList, and iterate through each node and check the attribute until you find one or more matches:

Sample C# code (I'd write VB but I'm quite rusty):

```
XmlNodeList nodes = myDoc.SelectNodes("Transaltions/language");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
   XmlElement elem = (XmlElement)node;
   if (elem.GetAttribute("code") == hLang.Value) {
      //elem is your match
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this, for this case i guess it would work, not sure for the other cases, i will let you know.

Comment: One other option is to take a proactive approach against XPath injection by creating a helper method that strips any XPath related markup out of the incoming string, then using the filtered sting in your XPath.

Answer (score 1):

**The main idea in preventing an XPath injection is to pre-compile the XPath expression you want to use and to allow variables (parameters) in it, which during the evaluation process will be substituted by user-entered values**.

**In .NET**:

1. Have your XPath expresion pre-compiled with **[XPathExpression.Compile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163317.aspx)**.
2. Use the **[XPathExpression.SetContext()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs084hw.aspx) Method** to specify as context an **[XsltContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext.aspx)** object that resolves some specific variables to the user-entered values.

You can read more about how to evaluate an XPath expression that contains variables **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567715.aspx)**.

This text contains good and complete examples.

Comment: can you explain me how can i use the context to archive what im trying to do? im havent been able to do it, i implemented EricL proposal for a specific case but i cant do it for most of my cases.

Comment: @LuisTellez, You'll evaluate this string: `"Translations/language[@code=$userInput]"` . You'll set the variable `$userInput` in your XsltContext object -- to contain the user's input. You'll evaluate the above string, using your XsltContext object as the context for the evaluation of this XPath expression. All of this is well-explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltcontext.aspx

Comment: There is no documentation that or examples arround that show me this is possible, they resolve context but cant evaluate variables and filter by them

Comment: @LuisTellez, You override the `ResolveVariable()` method, so that depending on the variable name, this method returns the corresponding user-entered string. And you pass this XsltContext as parameter to the Evaluate() method.